# Pandas read_csv declaration dtype convets column incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

When I use pandas to read a csv file, I set the `dtype` by using a dictionary (`dict_types`) in order to save memory:

```py
dict_types = {
    "Id": "object",
    "COD_OPE": "object",
    "NUM_OPE": "float32",
    "STR_ANA": "category",
    "COD_EXO": "category",
    "NUM_CPT": "object",
    "MTT_DEV": "float32",
    "SEN_MTT": "category",
}
columns = [
    "Id",
    "COD_OPE",
    "NUM_OPE",
    "STR_ANA",
    "COD_EXO",
    "NUM_CPT",
    "MTT_DEV",
    "SEN_MTT",
    "DTE_OPE", 
    "DTE_CPT",
    "DTE_VAL", 
    "DTE_TRT"
]
df_chunk = pd.read_csv(
    "../SIDP_Operations/SAB_OPE_02_2020/SAB_OPE_02_2020.rpt",
    sep="\t",
    dtype=dict_types,
    usecols=columns,
    error_bad_lines=False,
    chunksize=1000000,
    parse_dates=["DTE_OPE", "DTE_CPT", "DTE_VAL", "DTE_TRT"],
    infer_datetime_format=True,
)
```

But, when the file is loaded and I look at `df.info()` and  `df.dtypes`, it tells me that the type of `STR_ANA` is `object` while I expect it should be `category`.
And "COD_EXO" "SEN_MTT" is indeed type  `category`

Why?

maybe it because the way that i use chunk ?
actually i did this to read the dataframe

```
chunk_list=[] 
for chunk in df_chunk: 
    chunk_list.append(chunk) 
df=pd.concat(chunk_list,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Did you try to convert it manually with `df_chunk['STR_ANA'] = df_chunk['STR_ANA'].astype('category')` after you import your data?

Comment: What is the output of `df_chunk.dtypes()`?

Comment: Yes, use  `df_chunk['STR_ANA'] = df_chunk['STR_ANA'].astype('category') ` will work, but what i am trying to do is to save memory at the begining of reading the data, because my computer is so poor to read all of the data ...

Comment: the `df_chunk.dtypes()` is object too for the colonne 'STR_ANA' and other colonnes which should be category ...

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to use pd.concat() but it's better to add `ignore_index=True` to avoid duplicity of indexes.

```
df = pd.concat(df_chunk, ignore_index=True)
```

You have filled in 4 columns for the parameter `parse_dates` which do not exist in `columns`.

Make sure that the column names in your csv file are the same as the names for the `dtypes` and `usecols` you are assigning. To be sure, use the parameter `header=N` to ensure that pandas use the N line of the csv as your header.

Try this :

```
# add 4 columns with date
columns = [
    "Id",
    "COD_OPE",
    "NUM_OPE",
    "STR_ANA",
    "COD_EXO",
    "NUM_CPT",
    "MTT_DEV",
    "SEN_MTT",
    "DTE_OPE", "DTE_CPT", "DTE_VAL", "DTE_TRT"
]
df_chunk = pd.read_csv(
    "../SIDP_Operations/SAB_OPE_02_2020/SAB_OPE_02_2020.rpt",
    sep="\t",
    header=0,
    usecols=columns,
    dtype=dict_types,
    parse_dates=["DTE_OPE", "DTE_CPT", "DTE_VAL", "DTE_TRT"],
    infer_datetime_format=True,
    chunksize=1000000,
    error_bad_lines=False,
    low_memory=False
)
```

If it's still not working, try to remove `low_memory=False`.

Comment: hello, actually i did `chunk_list=[]` `for chunk in df_chunk:  chunk_list.append(chunk)` `df=pd.concat(chunk_list)`, is there a difference between this and get_chunk() ?

Comment: Please try solution v2.

Comment: thanks a lot ! I've tried all this but unfortunately this doesn't work for me ... it's really akward